# "composer update" only patch level

Tags: composer-php

Is there a way to limit "composer update" to update packages at patch level only, although I have minor version included by package definition.

Like:

```
composer --level=patch update
```

With composer.json:

```
"require": {
    "craftcms/cms": "4.*"
}
```

- Would do: 4.1.12 -> 4.1.13
- Would not do: 4.1.12 -> 4.2.1

Reason for this: our IT rules require to have sec-checks by external consultants with new minor versions but not with patch level updates only.

Comment: Why not use the proper constraints? `4.*` will obviously install all packages from v4

Comment: As I wrote, I do not generally want to block minor versions. Only for certain update processes where I am not allowed to update minor versions without additional security checks.

Comment: Then why not run these updates selectively? `composer update craftcms/cms` would solely update that single package, `composer update craftcms/cms:4.1.13` would soley update that single package to a specific version

Comment: Because I have > 30 directly required packages and hundreds dependent packages. Would be impossible or hours of work.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem and also have not found a native way to do that. However [`composer outdated`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#outdated) now has the `-p` or `-patch-only` option. I hope at some time this will be available for `update` as well. You can utilize this for a little script that does only update the patch versions like this for example:

```php
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

$outputJsonStr = shell_exec('composer outdated -p --format=json');
$outputJson = json_decode($outputJsonStr, true, 512, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR);

$updatePackages = [];

foreach ($outputJson['installed'] as $package) {
    if ($package['latest-status'] === 'semver-safe-update') {
        $updatePackages[] = $package['name'] . ':' . $package['latest'];
        echo $package['name'] . ':' . $package['version'] . ' -> ' . $package['latest'] . "\n";
    }
}

if (!empty($updatePackages)) {
    $packagesToStr = implode(' ', $updatePackages);
    echo "Updating packages: " . $packagesToStr . "\n";
    shell_exec('composer update ' . $packagesToStr);
} else {
    echo "No packages need to be updated.";
}
```